# API Access with Devise Authentication - Best Practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, devise

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in a Rails app and want to expose some of the model data via an API, but access to the API should be restricted just like the app.

```
$ curl http://myapp.com/api/v1/sales/7.json
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

Obviously.

Is there a best practice for accessing the API in situations like this? I'd *prefer* to authenticate + grab the data in one step, but that's just to make the client's job easier. They'll be pulling in the data client-side with JQuery.

Thanks for any info!

- Vanessa

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you follow the **Option 2: Using API Key** section on the following post to implement API authentication in Rails.

- http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2008/11/25/how_to_make_an_api_for_a_rails_app/

It's lightweight and simply requires passing an `api_key` param with each request.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would to generate an API "key" (hash value) and have that passed with the json request.  That way you can authenticate and track API use.  A lot of APIs use "keys" to track and authenticate use.  Google maps for instance, they use just an API key.  Where as PayPal uses a user name, password, and key.  There are a number of ways to do it.

I would try creating a one-to-many table that belongs to the user, just for keys.  That way a user can generate more than one hash key for different purposes.  (One for reports, one for backup, one for fancy pie charts that automagically pull from Powerpoint).